# Vaadin Calendar event selected style change on click

Tags: java, vaadin

I am trying to change the style of an event in the Vaadin Calendar component when clicking on it. This is what I do:

```
eventCalendar.setHandler((CalendarComponentEvents.EventClick event) -> {
    /* some code to iterate the container and remove selected style from other events*/
    ((BasicEvent) event.getCalendarEvent()).setStyleName("event-selected");
});
```

But nothing happens. The class is not added.

Answer (score 0):

Some hours later, two observations saved the day:

Firstly, setting the style name on the event itself does not trigger a refresh, so we just need to add `eventCalendar.markAsDirty()` to the handler method.

Secondly, `setStyleName` doesn't add a CSS class with that name to the Calendar Event element. It adds a class with the `.v-calendar-event-` prefix (e.g. in my example that would become `.v-calendar-event-event-selected`.

So, the solution was to make the following update to the UI class:

```
eventCalendar.setHandler((CalendarComponentEvents.EventClick event) -> {
    /* some code to iterate the container and remove selected style from other events*/
    ((BasicEvent) event.getCalendarEvent()).setStyleName("selected");
    eventCalendar.markAsDirty();
});
```

and add the following class to the `styles.scss`, inside the root name of the Vaadin theme:

```
.v-calendar-event-selected{
        /*however I wanted the selected event to look like*/
    }
```